# Is it possible to change section color using jquery while scrolling more than 50% of screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with 12 sections. I want a shadow to be on each section before it is scrolled to 50%. After scrolling, the shadow will disappear. How can I use jquery to accomplish this?

Comment: window.onscroll and scrollTop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the native method of the HTML element `getBoundingClientRect` This method returns rectangle dimensions of element. So you can get height of the window object, divide it on 2 and compare with the rectangle top value. If top value less then or equal to half of the window height you need to remove shadow from such element. All actions above you need to do on scroll event
Simple Example:

```
var shadowEdgePoint = $(window).height() / 2;
$(window).on('scroll', function(e){
    $('.sections-class').each(function(){
        if(this.getBoundingClientRect().top <= shadowEdgePoint){
             $(this).removeClass('shadowClass') ;
        }
        else{
             $(this).addClass('shadowClass') ;
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Would you please send me example what is the code ?

Comment: Hi MysterX, Would you please help me again i have one section inside 2 DIV's where  the div's name 1st div and 2nd div . By Default 2nd div will be hidden, after scrolling 50% or more 1st div will be hidden and 2nd div will be displayed. How do i do that?

Comment: Hey @Saiful. You should do in the same way as above, on `'scroll'` event get this two divs separately and check their top vs middle of the screen. `$('.first').get(0).getBoundingClientRect().top;` `$('.second').get(0).getBoundingClientRect().top;` and then do staff

Comment: Hey Boss MysterX, i am tired to fix this. Would you please send me the code example how i use $('.first').get(0).getBoundingClientRect().top; $('.second').get(0).getBoundingClientRect().top; please help me boss.